# Insert new records into a table with Visual Basic using OLEDBConnection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express and Access 2003.
I'm trying to make sql querys to the mdb file. I'm using OLEDBConnection. The Select query works fine, but I can't insert rows in the table. Here is the code.

```
    Dim connStr As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\tpv.mdb;" 
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr)
    con.Open()
    Dim query As String = "select * from Productos"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con)
    Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read()
        MsgBox(reader.GetValue(0) & ", " & reader.GetValue(1) & " , " & reader.GetValue(2))
    End While
    reader.Close()
    query = "insert into Productos (NombreProducto,PrecioCoste) VALUES ('cana',4)"
    Dim cmd2 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

Why the INSERT query does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my stupid problem.
Althoug I have declared 2 OleDbCommands, I referenced the first one in both cases